# Logging all events to a file on Angular

Tags: angular, logging

I need to log all the events that happen in a particular part of my Angular application to a file that will be located in the server.

I understand Angular is clientside so it has no access to files in the server.

Other ways of doing this are also accepted.

Comment: if you can explain why you want this feature, then I think people can provide you appropriate solution

Comment: A user has reported the application freezing when executing a particular function, I have tried to replicate with no luck. The idea is to find out exactly what's going on.

Comment: I think Ajmal Ali has given you the right answer if it serves your purpose don't forget to mark it as accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [NGX logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger) for logging.